# How do you declare a variable in one function and reference it in another using python?

Tags: python, static

Say I have this code:

```
def Declare():
    x = 5

def Print():
    print(x)

Declare()
Print()
```

This would throw an error because in the Print() function, x isn't defined. Is there a way to create a static variable that can be referenced anywhere using python?

Comment: No, there isn't. Essentially,  Python has module-level global scope and local scopes. You could create a global variable (generally considered a bad practice) and use that, of course, it would only be global in that module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
def declare():
    global x
    x = 5

def print_x():
    global x
    print(x)

declare()
print_x()
```

A few remarks:

- generally, global variables aren't a good solution and you should probably look at better ways of passing data between functions;
- don't capitalise your function names (or use capitals at all in function and variable names), capitals in Python indicate classes, not functions;
- don't define stuff that 'shadows' standard Python keywords and library functions, unless you really must (note I changed `print` to `print_x`;
- this would also work without the `global x` in `print_x`, since that function has access to the global scope when it runs, so it's a matter of preference to put it in. `global` is only required if you want to define and modify the variable in the global scope.

Comment: `global` is unnecessary (and IMO misleading) in `print_x`, global declarations signify that the variable will be *assigned to* and is meant to be gloabl.

Comment: I agree that it's unnecessary - I literally amended the answer while you posted the comment; I assume you agree with what is written?